# What are the spoilers in the DLC missions?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

Trying to start the DLC missions before completing the main game gives a warning about spoilers before letting the Player accept them.

What spoilers are there, so I know when I can safely start the missions? I also don't want to look up the missions, because then I'll be spoiled.

I know from around the 'net that "Dawn of the Rise of the Machines", a.k.a the "Surfing to the Robot Factory" mission involves Buck National, but is it just that he exists is the spoiler?

Similar with the "Mooil Rig" DLC. I know that Bryllcream exists, which might be a spoiler, since the quest can be gotten before meeting Troop Bushido, and because the quest is called "Find Bryllcream...Again", and looking up the game spoiled the end of it, which indicates that

> His sister exists and is dead

But those are only revealed in the DLC, so those aren't spoilers for the main story.

Are there more spoilers beyond the existence of certain characters?